# Joi.ref() equivalent in Zod for Object literal validation

Tags: typescript, joi, zod

I have a task of converting a code base from using Joi to Zod for TypeScript validation. In that process, I've run into a roadblock of finding an equivalent to joi.ref() in the zod library.

```
const joiParentObject = joi.object({
    someKey: joi.string().required()
})

const joiChildObject = joiParentObject.keys({
    someChildKey: joi.string().default(joi.ref('someKey'))
})

const zodParentObject = z.object({
    someKey: z.string()
})

const zodChildObject = z.object({
    someChildKey: z.string().... <---- here
}).merge(zodParentObject)
```

I've tried using different object literal methods, like `function someChildKey() {...}` or `get someChildKey(){}` and `set someChildKey(){}` but they all ended up with the `object is possibly undefined` when using the `this.` accessor for the sibling key from the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want `someChildKey` to be optional (i.e. `string | undefined`), and if it's `undefined`, you want it to have the value of `someKey`?

[Zod has a `.default()` method](https://zod.dev/?id=default), and you can pass it a default value or a function that evaluates to a default value, but you can't access the object's other properties in the function. So in this case the `.default()` method can't be used (but I mentioned it because it can be useful in simpler cases).

One solution is to mark `someChildKey` as optional using [Zod's `.optional()` method](https://zod.dev/?id=optional) and set a default value for it after parsing using [Zod's `.transform()` method](https://zod.dev/?id=transform):

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const parentObject = z.object({
  someKey: z.string(),
})

const childObject = z
  .object({
    someChildKey: z.string().optional(),
  })
  .merge(parentObject)
  .transform((data) => ({
    ...data,
    someChildKey: data.someChildKey ?? data.someKey,
  }))
```

Inside the `.transform()`, the `data` parameter is the whole object, so `data.someKey` is kind of the same as `Joi.ref('someKey')`.

---

By the way, [Joi's `object.keys()` method](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#objectkeysschema) seems to forbid undefined keys. For a similar effect, you can use [Zod's `.strict()` method](https://zod.dev/?id=strict).